# Rails 4 active record and models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am somewhat rusty with rails let me explain what I was doing with PHP and maybe someone can help tell me the correct way in rails 4.

I have several DB tables (we can call them) foo, bar, mar Each table holds a different level of reports data. In PHP I crated a homepage that loads what I called a suite view which is a complex query that pulls data from the 3 tables to group it together.  For a simple example every test run with an ID of foo gets pulled out and clumped in a suite.  This is all done with SQL there is no Suite DB table it dos not exist.

In rails I made models for foo, bar and mar but I don't know how to make my suite code work.  I would like a model that is called suite that is not based off a table but off a multi table query.  then the view can interact with the model as normal?

Im not sure if thats possible or the correct way.

Comment: can you add your existing code and your query please? For me your problem sounds just like some "where-do-i-have-to-put-the-code-to" problem.. You should not need an extra model just for querying some stuff.. you could put that in your other models.. but with a bit of code from you it would be easier to help you..

Comment: Ok so maybe its me then.  I want a view thats called suites.  the data for the table on the suites page is just a complex query pulling data from a few tables.  I was thinking I needed / wanted a model behind that view maybe I don't need one.?  have the suites view talk to what?  my existing code in php is just a data table with a select from foo, bar ....  so not helpful for how I thought rails would want the data.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can base you Rails model on view instead of a table. You will not be able to create/update/delete records, but it should work well enough for retrieving data. To do it just pass a view name instead of a table name to the `table_name` attribute of your model.

```
class MiniPost < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = 'posts_view'
end
```